# Errno::ETIMEDOUT not being caught by SystemCallError

Tags: ruby, exception

I have a section of code in Ruby 1.8.7

```
 rescue SystemCallError
```

But the program occasionally exits with `Errno::ETIMEDOUT`. Isn't the SytemCallError supposed to catch all Errno errors?

EDIT: The code is

```
 rescue SystemCallError, StandardError
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

It certainly should be!  Are you sure that `rescue` is in the path of the error that's being thrown?

```
>> Errno::ETIMEDOUT.superclass
SystemCallError
>> Errno::ETIMEDOUT.new.is_a? SystemCallError
true
```

Also:

```
>> begin
?>   raise Errno::ETIMEDOUT, "Fail, please"
>> rescue SystemCallError, StandardError
>>   puts "Caught #{$!.inspect}"
>> end
Caught #<Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Operation timed out - Fail, please>
```

Comment: Fairly certain, I'll double check the stack trace though. Would it matter if it was re-raised?

Comment: I don't think re-raising would cause a problem (unless it's being wrapped by a different exception class)

Comment: Wouldn't be surprising if there's some hokey special-casing going on under the covers that is breaking this :-/  I seem to remember that the POSIX exception classes are generated strangely

Comment: One test might be to remove the whitelist of classes entirely and see what you get via `$!`